# Example for using directions in Mapbox GL-JS

Tags: directions, mapbox-gl-js

The [example for using the directions plugin](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/) doesn't seem to be working, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

By the look of it, however, it doesn't do what I want anyway. I want to offer users directions using a specific group of objects (to [buildings on our university campus](https://maps.unimelb.edu.au/parkville/building/) from the users' current location, or another building)

I'm hoping for an example that just provides a start and finish lat/lng and triggers a request for directions.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions plugin was fixed with a new release yesterday, so that example you posted should work now.

You can check out how to make a request to the directions API using LatLng pairs in our [api-docs](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#directions) and test it out in our [API Playground](https://www.mapbox.com/api-playground/#/directions/).

Comment: Thanks for that, yes, they're working now. As I said, though, sadly they example doesn't fit my needs, and although it can be done using the API, I'm afraid it's all a bit beyond me.

I need to be able to generate directions from variables I supply in the page - both hard coded (as in a set destination), and dynamically provided (as in another set location, or the users' current location).

Maybe someone has an example, or some pointers to get me started. Otherwise I'm going to need to find someone with a bit more js skill!